# retrieveing substring using regular expression?

Tags: regex, oracle

My friend they are like ummm file name which has specific format should be written with like first year (YY) then month (MM) then that sequential number (SEQ) and stored in database and I have to check that all files are exist with same year and same month so...

I'm using regex to catch theses parts to check that concept... and thanks for your help
I'm using the where clause to filter records then I use substr to catch these part I told you about so the query will be something like that..

```
Select substr(column_name1,4,4),substr(column_name1,0,2),substr(column_name1,2,2), 
  into seqvar,yearvar,dayvar 
  from table1 
 where regex_like (FILENAME,'(CDR-)([1-9][0-9]{0,3})(_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{4}_UK1\.FCDR)
```

is it best way and fastest to do something like that ??

or using like clause insted of regex at where cluase are better ??

please all your opinion with that case

Comment: you want [1-9][0-9]{0,3} from 'CDR-([1-9][0-9]{0,3})_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{4}_UK1\.FCDR' ? right ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the part/group you have mentioned , use this :

```
`/\((.*?)\)/`
```

try this in your firebug

```
var str = 'CDR-([1-9][0-9]{0,3})_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{4}_UK1\.FCDR';
var res = /\((.*?)\)/.exec(str);
console.log(res[1]);
```

will output : `[1-9][0-9]{0,3}`

if you want output like `([1-9][0-9]{0,3})`

use : `/(\(.*?\))/`

Comment: I have around million and a half record I want to get that part from all of them then check if that part is sequential

Comment: so I cant specificy the variable contain

Answer (score 0):

Since oracle doesn't support lookaheads, maybe it will be easyer to use [REGEXP_REPLACE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm)

May look like this:

```
select regexp_replace(FILENAME, '(CDR-)([1-9][0-9]{0,3})(_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{4}_UK1\.FCDR)', '\2')
  from ....
```

Comment: ok thats will get the SEQ part I talked about , but What I really Need is to save that part at variable or something to use that part to check the 1 million and a half records if they are sequentially or not and get the  missing number from the whole list HOW ?

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but how can 1,500,000 rows have a 4 digit sequence ? Anyway, why can't you hold the value in a variable? `SELECT regexp.... INTO your_variable FROM ...`. But you can also have another view of he sequential numbers and left outer join it with your query